# Listening for events on dynamically added elements/event propogation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Trying to build a to do list app with jQuery/Django, my `Task` model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

a user should be able to add a task(this is working) and click on a task to updated it's `task.completed` value to `True` and give it a `text-decoration:line-through`, this is sort of working. I can only update task objects that existed when the page was first loaded, if I add another task object via ajax and try it click that one without refreshing the page, nothing happens.

Html:

```
  <div class="col-8 mt-5">
    <form id = "createTaskForm" class="form-inline justify-content-center" method="post" data-url = "{% url 'task_list_url' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        <div class="mx-3">{{ field }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button id = "createButton" type="button" class = "btn btn-outline-success">Sumbit</button>
    </form>
  </div>


  <div id = "taskList" class="col-5 mt-5">
    {% for task in tasks %}
      <div id = "taskCard" class="task card mb-1" data-id="{{task.id}}" style="{% if task.completed %}text-decoration:line-through{% endif %}">
        <div class=" card-body">
          {{task.title}}
          <button type="button" class = "close float-right">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

JS  (Edit, going to include the code that adds a card to the page in case the problem is there) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  let csrfToken = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()

  $('#createButton').on( "click", function() {
    let serializedData = $('#createTaskForm').serialize();


    $.ajax({

      url: $("#createTaskForm").data('url'),

      data: serializedData,
      type: 'post',
      success: function(response) {
        $("#taskList").append(`
          <div class="card mb-1">
            <div class="card-body" data-id="${response.task.id}">
              ${response.task.title}
              <button type="button" class = "close float-right">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          `)
      }
    })
    // Clear input field after submission
    $("#createTaskForm")[0].reset()
  });

  $('#taskList').on('click', '.card', function(){
    let dataId = $(this).data('id');
    console.log($(this));
    $.ajax({
      url: '/tasks/' +dataId +'/completed/',
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken,
        id: dataId
      },
      type: 'post',
      success: function(){
        let cardItem = $(`#taskCard[data-id="${dataId}"]`);
        cardItem.css('text-decoration', 'line-through').hide().slideDown();
        $('#taskList').append(cardItem);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Not sure if these are needed but,
Django views:

```
class TaskList(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = TaskForm()
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'task/task_list.html', {'form': form, 'tasks': tasks})

    def post(self, request):
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            new_task = form.save()
            # send task object as json response
            # this return value is what is in success: function(response)
            return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(new_task)}, status=200)
        else:
            return redirect('task_list_url')

class TaskComplete(View):
    def post(self, request, id):
        task = Task.objects.get(id=id)
        task.completed = True
        task.save()
        return JsonResponse({'task': model_to_dict(task)}, status = 200)
```

Django URLs:

```
path('', TaskList.as_view(), name = 'task_list_url'),
path('<str:id>/completed/', TaskComplete.as_view(), name = 'task_complete_url'),
```

Back to the jQuery code, I was reading about event delegation at https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and thought I did this right. It seems to say that if I were to add the event listener on just the `.card` elements, as such:

```
$('.card').on('click', function(){
  // code here
});
```

I would run into the problem where event listeners were only attached to `.card`s that existed when the page was first loaded. However, if I attach the event listener to a parent element and pass in `.card` as the second parameter, it will be able to listen for events on all descendant `.card` elements, even if they were added after the page was loaded(though I don't really understand how this concept works). Anyway, can anyone help me get this to work? Thank

Comment: `$('taskList').append(cardItem)` is missing the `#`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you didn't notice that as the effects were still taking place the .card just wasn't being moved to the bottom of the list. But the problem remains after this change.

Comment: Event delegation would be `$('.card').on('click',` -> `$(document).on('click', '.card',`.  You have this as `$('#taskList').on('click', '.card', ` - but it depends on what `$("#taskList")` is and if *that* gets loaded/reloaded.  That's one reason people just default to `$(document)`

Comment: Alternatively, the code to add the new `.card` is not working as expected, eg a typo - you've not included that code.

Comment: *though I don't really understand how this concept works* - the learn jquery page should provide enough details.  In summary:  the click events *bubble up* to their parents if they this bubble feature is not cancelled.  So clicking on .card will also send a click event to #taskList.  You can then put an event handler on #taskList and check if the actual clicked element was a .card; jquery does this for you.

Comment: DOM IDs must be unique.   You are already repeating IDs `id=taskCard`, so it's possible you have a repeated `id=taskList` somewhere, so perhaps your event handler is picking the wrong taskList?

Comment: @freedomn-m just updated with that included

Comment: @freedomn-m Im sorry im messing this all up now, tried to remove the classes and extra bootstrap divs on my original post to make it more concise and then re-added them when I copy and pasted the code that adds a task to the page

Comment: Thanks for adding code.  Please clarify on "*nothing happens*" - does your click event get fired?  There's no reason it should not fire.  There *is* an issue with the line after that, but let's be sure the event fires first.

Comment: Your issue is with:  `let dataId = $(this).data('id');` inside the click event.  On the page load, these are `<div class="task card" data-id="{{task.id}}"` so click event picks up the id, but on your 1st edit, you add a card as:  `<div class="card mb-1"><div class="card-body" data-id="${response.task.id}">` so `$(this)` (the .card) does **not have a data-id**.   In your 2nd edit, the html you add doesn't even have a `card` class, so we'll ignore that.

Comment: On client side the code which creates and appends a new task item to the task list misses to provide the most important event delegation data, the class name(s) of a task item.

Comment: @freedomn-m I had just realized that while trying to clean this up, thank you for taking the time to figure this out. Will update the code on here but that was the problem, it is working now.

Comment: @freedomn-m Not sure if I would have ever realized that as the card was still being added to the page, just without that attribute